# How to set background color for suggestions in Autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

I'm working on a React application with Material-UI, and I'm using the Autocomplete component to provide search suggestions. I'm having trouble setting the background color specifically for the suggestions in the dropdown menu.

I've tried applying the background color to the Paper component inside the List, but it's affecting more than just the suggestions.

Here is the code of the search bar component that I wrote:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    TextField, InputAdornment, IconButton, List, ListItem, Paper,
} from '@mui/material';
import { Search as SearchIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import 'index.css';

type SearchBarProps = {
  onSearch: (query: string) => void;
};

const suggestions = ['React', 'JavaScript', 'TypeScript', 'CSS', 'HTML', 'Material-UI', 'GraphQL'];

export const SearchBar: React.FC<SearchBarProps> = ({ onSearch }) => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>('');
    const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [activeSuggestion, setActiveSuggestion] = useState<number | null>(null);

    const handleSearchChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const query = event.target.value;

    setSearchQuery(query);
    // Filter suggestions based on the input
    setFilteredSuggestions(suggestions.filter((suggestion) => suggestion.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())));
    setActiveSuggestion(null); // Reset active suggestion on input change
  };

  const handleSuggestionClick = (suggestion: string) => {
    setSearchQuery(suggestion);
    onSearch(suggestion);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]); // Clear suggestions after selecting one
    setActiveSuggestion(null); // Reset active suggestion after selection
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowDown' && activeSuggestion !== null) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setActiveSuggestion((prev) => (prev !== null && prev < filteredSuggestions.length - 1 ? prev + 1 : prev));
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' && activeSuggestion !== null) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setActiveSuggestion((prev) => (prev !== null && prev > 0 ? prev - 1 : prev));
    } else if (event.key === 'Enter' && activeSuggestion !== null) {
      event.preventDefault();
      handleSuggestionClick(filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Reset active suggestion when filtered suggestions change
    setActiveSuggestion(null);
  }, [filteredSuggestions]);

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        className="searchBar"
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={searchQuery}
        onChange={handleSearchChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        style={{
            width: '200px',
            marginBottom: '20px',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: '10px',
          }}
          InputProps={{
            style: { color: 'black' },
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton onClick={() => onSearch(searchQuery)} edge="end">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
      />
      {filteredSuggestions.length > 0 && (
        <List>
          {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => (
            <ListItem
                button
                key={suggestion} // or use another unique identifier if available
                onClick={() => handleSuggestionClick(suggestion)}
                selected={index === activeSuggestion}
          >
              <Paper style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>{suggestion}</Paper>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I set the background color only for the suggestions in the dropdown menu without affecting other elements on the page? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This is how it is right now]

[image: This is how it should be]

Comment: The question claims [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) is used. Yet **Autocomplete** does not appear in the code. Where is Autocomplete being used?